# Memory analysis for a process

Tags: c++, memory, process

I have a process which calls/creates another process, and this one will load a bunch of modules. The thing is that these modules will all be loaded in the same process as the caller (by default). Is there any way that I can collect resources information for the individual loaded module, even through they are all on one big process?

Comment: What kind of screwy operating system does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in a situation where a process loaded some modules, these modules loaded lots of data from a database and put them this data in STL and Boost containers (std::set, std::map, std::vector, boost::multiindex). And since most of memory was used by these containers my task was to measure how much memory each container used.

If it looks like your task then you can add your own counting allocators to each container and after that you will have information about memory consumption.